# how to execute function retrieve from database in php with mysql..?

Tags: php

I have a database table with the name of `validation` that contains data like

```
 vNo    Chkvalidate
   1    Check_Value ('Category_Code', '', '', '1', '', '1')=1
   2    Check_Value ('Category_Code', '', '', '2', '', '')=1 AND Check_Value ('Subject_Code', '', '', '1', '', '1')=1
```

The function definitions written in `validation.php` file like this:

```php
 function Check_Value($col_name, $to_range, $from_range, $list_value, $stat, $counter)
    {
      // Some definition here...
    }
```

How can I invoke the function `Check_Value` when I fetch record row by row from validation table...?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is exactly? Fetching the records, or something else?

Comment: It seems you not only want to invoke it but also compare against a value (`=1`)? The function that shall not be named seems to be the easiest way.... but its evil!

Comment: Please show us your real database schema and data. Is this the same `Check_Value` function as in your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615468/how-to-explode-array-within-array-in-php

Comment: PEkka: my problem is that when i fetch the records from database can i invoke the function on the basis of the record...?

Comment: mario: Check_Value function is a function store in a table but its definition  store in validation.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use PHP's [eval](http://www.php.net/eval) function to evaluate the string you obtain from the database.

That said, I'd be **very** tempted to re-factor the offending part of the application, as storing (and subsequently evaluating) functions that reside in a database gives off such a strong [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) that a gas mask is required.